# date with additional -0500 or -0600 in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with dates in the following format.

```
date
2018-09-03 07:56:29 -0500
2018-03-29 14:03:52 -0600
```

I want to convert them to the following format without changing the time zone (I don't know if the time zone could be an issue in this case. The column doesn't specify the time zone. I live in Mexico. I would prefer to have dates according to Mexico time zone. The time zone of Mexico city is UTC-5h when DST start and UTC-6h when DST end.)

```
date
2018-09-03 07:56:29 AM
2018-03-29 14:03:52 PM
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The date format you show implies that the data is in Zulu time (or Greenwich Mean Time, or Universal Time). That means they are adjusted to the UTC time by subtracting the hours shown at the end.

If you simply ignore the adder, your times will be wrong, depending on where they were taken. For example, the first one has `-0500`, which is EST (Eastern US time), but the second line with `-0600` is CST (Central US time). So they were measured in two different time zones, which are one hour apart. You cannot ignore that without introducing error.

The correct interpretation is to convert them to your target timezone (I am not sure which time zone Mexico is on - CST?).
Adding the `AM` or `PM` to it is superfluous, as the PM times are shown as 12:01 - 23:59, whereas the AM times will be 00:01 - 11:59. You can certainly add it, to make it easier to read for people who are not used to use a 24-h clock, but they don't contain new information.

Comment: The time zone of Mexico city is UTC-5h when DST start and UTC-6h when DST end.